# Compiling the Command Line Wallet

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-cli, monero-wallet-rpc, third-party-wallets

How do I build the command line wallet for linux?

Example:

- monero-wallet-cli
- monero-wallet-rpc
- monerod

Where can I get the source code? 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The source for the Monero tools is on http://github.com/monero-project/monero.
Compiling's done with "make". See the README.md file for the necessary dependencies, and detailed build steps for various platforms.

Note that the GUI is on http://github.com/monero-project/monero-core.

Comment: Does this work if I use the cryptonote code??

Comment: If you mean the original CryptoNote repository, I don't know. The above applies to Monero and its derivatives.